# Serial-Ethernet or Serial-WiFi (or Serial-Bluetooth?) on OS X

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, driver

I'm trying to connect a remote serial port to my MacBook Pro (and potentially other devices such as Windows or laptops, and Android tablets and smartphones) wirelessly.

I've come across Serial-WiFi and Serial-Ethernet adaptors (the latter could presumably be connected to a router and accessed via my existing wifi network), but I don't know how to access the serial port from my Mac.
So far as I can tell tese devices rely on drivers which simulate a COM port on the computer, and so far as I can tell none of these adaptors come with drivers which work on OS X.
I see that there are also Serial-Bluetooth adaptors, which I guess would also suffice for my purpose if they could be made to work, but I assume the same issue exists with these.

In case it helps; this is for connecting the NMEA 0183 outputs of various marine navigational instruments to my computer, for use by navigational sftware such as (primarily) [OpenCPN](http://opencpn.org/ocpn/). For those who aren't familiar with it, NMEA 0183 is a protocol enabling marine navigational instruments to share data with each other via ASCII data sentences broadcast over a serial interface. [More details on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183).

If there's an alternative way to transmit this data to my computer over wifi, that would be equally acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth may actually be the way to go. There's no standard for Serial-WiFi or Serial-Ethernet adapters (as far as I know), so you'd be at the mercy of the manufacturers who need to provide OS X drivers. On the other hand, most Bluetooth functions come from a set of standardized profiles that don't need specific device drivers. For example, a headset just needs to implement the correct audio profile to be able to work with anything that supports that profile. Bluetooth serial adapters implement the Serial Port Profile, and OS X supports it.

Once you have one of those devices and have it paired, it will show up as a standard serial port device like /dev/cu.bluetooth and /dev/tty.bluetooth, just like a Serial-USB adapter.

If the serial port doesn't get created automaticaly, it can be [added manually in the Bluetooth advanced preferences](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10545). I also found an example of someone using SPP with a Mac here: 
[Using Bluetooth Serial Port on OS X Mountain Lion](http://ruoranwang.github.com/blog/2012/10/19/using-bluetooth-serial-port-on-os-x-mountain-lion/).

Comment: That's interesting; thanks. So if I understand correctly; an rs232-bluetooth adaptor would appear to software on the computer to be identical to a hardwired serial port? So I could simply connect my NMEA devices to it and it would be functionally identical to connecting them via a serial-USB adaptor, without having to install any drivers? If so then as you say, that certainly seems like the way to go.

Comment: I know this is the wrong place to ask, but do you know if this is also the case if I connected it to an Android device?  
The disadvantage here would presumably be that I could only connect it to one device at a time, whereas with ethernet/wifi I could connect it to multiple devices (if I could make it work at all).

Comment: That's right, it would be identical to hardwired, as far as the software is concerned (in theory, ethernet/wifi would work the same, but they'd need drivers first). I'm not sure how or if Android handles SPP. Bluetooth would definitely be limited to one device at a time, but I'm not sure ethernet/wifi would allow more than one either, even though NMEA is unidirectional.

Comment: Thanks @gabesubdo, that's great.
Regarding ethernet/wifi only working for one device at a time, why would this be? I mean, normally any device on a LAN can talk to any other, so why would this be different? Thinking aloud, perhaps because a serial port is only designed to be connected to one device, it simply wouldn't work connecting multiple devices to a serial port, even in software? Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming that the networked adapters would only allow one connection at a time just because that's what serial devices expect. They could design something to get around that limitation, but that takes effort to get right and I always assume that hardware manufacturers will do the minimum possible.